# EC2 running cost of each instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I need to monitor the cost of each vms that are running in my EC2 account. Is there any straight api to achieve this? If not, I'm looking for a way to obtain the price of the instances. The json file of the price seems to be deprecated. Is there any other way to obtain the price?

Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can enable billing details to your S3 bucket and every day it spits out a csv file to an S3 bucket with the detailed usage. You will have to pick up (using the AWS S3 API) and parse the file to get the specifics that you want.

More information on how to do it here:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/about/programaccess.html

The file you probably want to parse is `aws-billing-detailed-line-items-with-resources-and-tags`

[image: S3 Billing]